# Select all where the months of "date" is December in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Do you know if I can do a `findAll` where the month of `Date` is December?

I try this request but it's not good:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate({}, { "Date": { $month: 12 } });
```

it's similar to a `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Months(date)=december`?

Answer (score 3):

Consider running an aggregation pipeline that uses the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** operator as it allows you to incorporate with a single pipeline, a functionality with **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** to create a field that represents the month of a date field and **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** to filter the documents
which match the given condition of the month being December.

In the above, **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** uses **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** tenary operator as means to provide the conditional expression that will create the system variable which does the redaction. The logical expression in **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** will check
for an equality of a date operator field with a given value, if that matches then **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** will return the documents using the **[`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** system variable and discards otherwise using **[`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)**.

Running the following pipeline should give you the desired result:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$Date" }, 12] },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

---

This is similar to a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** +**[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** combo but you'd need to then select all the rest of the fields that go into the pipeline:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "month": { "$month": "$Date" },
            "field1": 1,
            "field2": 1,
            .....
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "month": 12 } }
])
```

---

With another alternative, albeit slow query, using the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** method and **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** as:

```
db.myCollection.find({ "$where": "this.Date.getMonth() === 11" })
```

Answer (score 0):

db.collection('mycollection').find({"Date": {$month: 12}})

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Answer (score -1):

This should work for finding records in December for a given year, if that is enough to suit your purposes.

```
db.myCollection.find({
    "Date":{
        $gte:new Date("2016-12-01T00:00:00Z"),
        $lt:new Date("2017-01-01T00:00:00Z")
}})
```